# Can a country that I live & pay taxes learn & know that I also pay taxes in another country?

Tags: taxes, international, germany, turkey

I am a Turkish national, pay taxes in Turkey, but also if live & work & pay taxes in a Germany, can the German government know & learn that I also pay taxes to Turkey?

Comment: Why would the tax bureau of country B care about that?

Comment: @Philipp there are a lot of reasons, but just assume that they care.

Comment: The only issue is whether you are misreporting your taxable assets to country B.

Comment: Depends entirely on which countries and what the circumstances are. Some information sharing does exist. This could even help you, by allowing you to get a foreign tax credit against taxes paid in one of the countries. Nothing can be said for certain without knowing your situation.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon see my edit please

Comment: Are you a citizen of Turkey or of Germany or of neither? E.g. if you are a US citizen, you _also_ owe taxes to the US on your worldwide income but you get a credit against the taxes due to the US for taxes paid to other countries. Since you live and pay taxes in Germany, what is your legal status in Germany?

Comment: @DilipSarwate see my lastest edit please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are international agreements between countries to enable exchange of information via [FATCA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Account_Tax_Compliance_Act) for US and [CRS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Reporting_Standard) internationally.

Both Turkey and Germany are signatories. All banks report qualifying accounts to country regulators and is available for exchange with member countries.